# Tweepy and csv error: unexpected parameter for include_rts and import json to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, tweepy

I restarted my project that I stopped doing a few years ago. With some research, I made the project compatible with the updated API versions and it worked without a problem. My code that worked 3 weeks ago is not working now. Firstly, I was getting an unexpected parameter errors from the include_rts and since command, after some research, I changed since to until and fixed it. When I remove the include rts from the codes and changed my keywords (I added them to -is=retweet) and the codes does not give an error, but the csv file from which I need to import the data is not created. Here are the code that I think might be the problem

```
           def write_tweets(keyword, file):
               if os.path.exists(file):
                  df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
               else:
                  df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLS)
                
               for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=keyword, count=200, include_rts=False, until='2021-12-26').pages(1):
        
                    for status in page:
                       new_entry = []
                       status = status._json
                        
                       single_tweet_df = pd.DataFrame([new_entry], columns=COLS)
                       df = df.append(single_tweet_df, ignore_index=True)
        
                       csvFile = open(file, 'a' ,encoding='utf-8')
                       df.to_csv(csvFile, mode='a', columns=COLS, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
        
elective_course_keywords = '#Parallel_Programming -is=retweet OR #Cloud_Computing -is=retweet Or #computer_science -is=retweet OR #machine_learning -is=retweet'
    
elective_course_tweets = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/TwitterDatas/elective_course_tweets_data.csv"
    
write_tweets(elective_course_keywords, elective_course_tweets)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that it is all about the changed version of the Tweepy library. Most likely your code is for version 3.10 or lower and worked in that version. Since version 4.0, Tweepy has undergone major internal changes. In order not to greatly redo the code, you can simply forcibly downgrade the Tweepy version to 3.10, then the old code will work again. My similar situation was resolved in this way.